# Stored procedure which returns table and being returned table gathers 1 rows from 9000 table

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I need a stored function which returns table and being returned table gathers 1 rows from all 9000 tables.

Prerequisites:

1. There are same structure 9000 tables.
2. Table name are subsquent, like X1000 X1001 .... X9999.
3. Issue query to all table and get 1 rows from all table.
4. Gather all rows and return as 1 table.
5. Envirnment are PostgreSQL 9.3 and PL/Pgsql

I hope you will give me some easy example.

I think I can not understand how to deal variable value.

I made myself, however it didn't work.

```
create or replace function ListOfInc
(ddate int) returns table(col1 int, col2 dec) as $$
declare
numofrow integer;
begin

for i in 1000..9999 loop
 numofrow := execute 'select count(*) from x' || i || ';';
 if numofrow > 0 then
    return query execute 'select ' || i || ' Trunc(100 * (CAST(Lag(adjust) over (order by' 
    || %1 || ') as dec) / CAST(adjust as dec) - 1) ,2) from x' || i || ' order by ' || %1  || ' desc limit 1;';
 end if;

end loop;

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: "Didn't work" how, exactly? Error message ...?

Comment: As sum of rows being over 9000000, I am not sure if View will work well or not, I will try to use union all, thank you.

Comment: It works!! thank you very much, however my computer does not enough memory to execute query. I will tune my postgre or buy new pc.

Comment: You shouldn't need tons of memory if you use a series of `union all`s in a single query. Certainly not if you use inheritance. If you're needing lots of RAM you're probably returning a whole result set from a function, in which case it has to be materialized in memory.

Comment: I read inheritance article, But  I could not understand inheritance. I will read it again and try to tune sql query, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ideal job for [PostgreSQL's inheritance features](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html).

If you want to avoid inheritance, you'll need to build a `union all` of all the tables using dynamic SQL, or loop over each table using `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE ...`.

Personally I recommend consolodating all the data into one table. Create views to emulate the old structure, so your apps don't notice the change.